# When you want to create a quiz, you get me

Tags: riddle

> When you want to create a quiz, you get me
>
> You can find me in the underground
>
> I'm in the course (maybe)...
>
> I'm in a list.

**Who am I?**

Hint 1

> Course is an anagram

Hint 2

> Underground is a way for explain another thing.

Answer (score 2):

You are

> Source

When you want to create a quiz, you get me

> You get a source of the answers

You can find me in the underground

> Many sources are found underground

I'm in the course(maybe)

> source is anagram of course

Im in a list

> You can have a list of sources

Comment: Quite question, but this isn't! You can get the solution in the source.

Answer (score 0):

You are

> a bunker

You can find me in the underground

> a bunker could be a safe haven in an air raid and as such is generally **underground**

I'm in the course (maybe)...

> a bunker could be an obstacle in a golf **course**, such as a sand trap

I'm in a list.

> anything could be in a list, here we could have a list of bunkers on the course or a list of nuclear bunkers in the United States.

Comment: Good answer, But It isn't! I add an hint on the question

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're

> an item

When you want to create a quiz, you get me

> not too sure about this one, maybe consider each question an item

You can find me in the underground

> underground could refer to the black market, where many items are sold

I'm in the course (maybe)...

> course is an anagram of source, so this could be a reference to source items

I'm in a list.

> elements of a list can be called items